# Animated gif doesn't animate during form processing

Tags: php, jquery, spinner

```
<form action="reg.php" method="post" onsubmit="spinn()">
 ...
```

form processing is long about 7 sec. (phpMailer inside)

```
function spinn(){
    $('#loading').html("<img src='spinn.gif' />");
}
```

`spinn.gif` is there, but - it doesn't animate !. Keeps as a common image.
At the same time ( during the form processing) spinner on Firefox's tab - is animated.

My RAM is 4GB - if matters.

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual spinn.gif?

Comment: If your form processing is sent to the server with `$.ajax` and `async: false`, there's nothing you can do other than changing from `async: false` to `async: true`.

Comment: @ithcy, this all happens on my localhost. phpMailer goes via Google SMTP, and it works, i.e. mail arrives. Where should I check about ajax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a thought... you might try having the html in there to start

`<img src='spinn.gif' style='display: none;' />`

Then in your code:

```
function spinn(){
    $('#loading').show();
}
```

It could be that the image needs to be preloaded, and it may not be able to do that while the form is submitting.